# init.d scripts and rc folders

Tags: services, autostart, init.d

I am wondering why not all scripts placed in `init.d` folder are in `rc` folders eg. system cups is in `init.d` but there is not in `rc` folders?

I don’t know if I understand it right. When I want to disable service I have to execute

```
 update-rc.d -f something remove
```

but do I have to delete this service file from `init.d` folder too ? because when I check

```
 service --status-all
```

after `update-rc.d -f something remove` this service is still present in the list. How to interpret it right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that cups service is an `upstart` job that run `/etc/init.d/cups` script.

Check if is present `/etc/init/cups.conf` and if it `exec /etc/init.d/cups`.

Regarding the removal of links in `rcX.d` you should remove your script in `/ect/init.d` before you run `update-rc.d` command, indeed according to [**update-rc.d**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) manual:

```
  When  invoked  with the remove option, update-rc.d removes any links in
  the /etc/rcrunlevel.d directories to the script /etc/init.d/name.   The
  script  must have been deleted already.  If the script is still present
  then update-rc.d aborts with an error message.
```

Comment: I have found this line in manual too. So the safest way is to disable not remove e.g. for testing purpose. So the best way to do this: **sudo update-rc.d something disable**